# Update a specific column of mysql table using django views

Tags: mysql, django

I have a mysql table with column id, username and token, where id and username is already given but token changes for every time. How to update it using django views.py
I am giving username for identity but it add a new row in the table

```
def hello(request):
    data=json.loads(request.body)
    s= Subscriber()
    s.username=data["username"]
    s.token=data["token"]
    s.save()
    print(data)
    return JsonResponse({"status": "success"})
```

Comment: Add your `views.py` so that we can help you better

Answer (score -1):

First get your `object` with `primary key` from your `Subscriber` Model and update the `token` with your new value as

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def hello(request, id): #<---- here i assumed you passed your id as url parameters
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    s= get_object_or_404(Subscriber, pk=id)
    s.username = data["username"] #<--- if required add otherwise for updating token this will not required
    s.token = data["token"]
    s.save()
    print(data)
    return JsonResponse({"status": "success"})
```

> I am giving username for identity

For `updating` single data always try to get your data with the `unique` field otherwise you may get `duplicate` data and will be difficult to handle. So I used `id` here to get data. You can just pass the `id` as `url` parameter and get the data according to the `id` provided. You can use `username` also if it is `unique` to get data but if you have more than one `username` with same value then it will throw `exception`. If you want to get data with `username` then just replace `pk=id` with `username=data['username']` and no need to pass `id` as url parameter then it will work.